# How can I remedy a 'TeX capacity exceeded, sorry' error?

Tags: errors

I'm trying to write a report that contains many `tikz` figures (originating from Matlab, if that matters). When I compile my document, I get the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually this error means that some macro is defined in terms of itself. Can you reduce the problem to a minimum example?

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be to be to externalize tikz figures.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
```

Together with this step, you’ll need to create a folder in the directory where your .tex file is located and name this folder ‘tikz’.

also you'll need to enable shell escape

pdflatex --shell-escape

This makes separate tex jobs for every tikz figure, which thus per figure has more tex capacity.

Source:
http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/